# Kotlin Gson null value

Tags: android, json, kotlin, null, gson

I am trying to form this type of JSON:

```
"answer_id":123,
"question_id":4567,
"value":"null"
```

However, i am not able to put NULL value at value key, seems like Gson is simply ignoring that field, so after serialization i get

```
"answer_id":123,
"question_id":4567
```

so my server throws bad request. I am using `serializeNulls()` in Gson builder which should allow nullable values but it does not work for me. Does anyone know what`s the problem?

```
@Parcelize
data class AnswerHelperObject(@SerializedName("question_id") val questionId: Int,
                              @SerializedName("value") val value: String? = null,
                              @SerializedName("answer_id") val answerId: Int?)

    : Parcelable {}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be a -> "value":null  ?

Comment: @jczerski Yes it should :) I mean, server requires that kind of response.

Comment: Are you sure is it a problem of GSON not http client problem?

Comment: Well, thing is that i do not get the field value in JSON if u put null. Seems like serializeNulls() option from Gson is not working.

Comment: Please add the code how you serialize. Do you have some DTO representing that JSON?

Comment: @pirho I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are receiving value as string Gson will parse it as String "null", you can write custom Deserializers if you want to have field value as null.

> AnswerHelperObject

```
data class AnswerHelperObject(
    var answer_id: Int,
    var question_id: Int,
    var value: String?
)
```

> AnswerHelperObjectDeserializer

```
class AnswerHelperObjectDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<AnswerHelperObject>{
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): AnswerHelperObject {
        val answerHelperObject = Gson().fromJson(json.asJsonObject, AnswerHelperObject::class.java)
        if (answerHelperObject.value == "null") {
            answerHelperObject.value = null
        }
        return answerHelperObject
    }
}
```

You can see the Test scenarios.

```
class AnswerHelperObjectTest {

    @Test
    fun answer_object_parse_as_null_string() {
        val json = "{\"answer_id\":123,\n" +
                "\"question_id\":4567,\n" +
                "\"value\":\"null\"}"

        val answerHelperObject = Gson().fromJson(json, AnswerHelperObject::class.java)
        // value is parsed as string of value null
        assertEquals(answerHelperObject.value, "null")
    }
    @Test
    fun answer_object_parse_null() {
        val json = "{\"answer_id\":123,\n" +
                "\"question_id\":4567,\n" +
                "\"value\":\"null\"}"

        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(AnswerHelperObject::class.java, AnswerHelperObjectDeserializer())
            .create()

        val answerHelperObject = gson.fromJson(json, AnswerHelperObject::class.java)
        // value is deserialized as null
        assertEquals(answerHelperObject.value, null)
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion you shouldn't try do sth like this and deserialize specific string as null. It's API error that null value is returned as `"null"` string, not as `null` value and API is the place where this should be fixed.

Comment: Again, it is not about deserializing, it's about serializing. I have fixed the error, it was about GsonConverterFactory provided by Dagger2. I have not passed the Gson as a dependency to the factory.